# Getting ora-01858 in SQL block

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Vcount varchar(20);


Select count(*) into vcount
from base_sales_ordrer
where status_lkp='2' and date_created between '01-may-20' and '31-may-20';
```

Comment: can you write some description about what are you trying to achieve and what is the problem that you are facing here.

Answer (score 0):

`VCOUNT` you named is irrelevant here; it is `DATE_CREATED` that makes problems. What is its datatype? I **hope** it is `DATE`, because you'd then fix it simply as

```
where date_created between date '2020-05-01' and date '2020-05-31'
```

Note that I used **date literals**; you used *strings*. Never compare dates to strings, various problems arise (you hit one of them).

---

But, if `date_created` is `VARCHAR2`, then you have a real problem as you'll first have to convert those values to dates and - if not all data follows the same format mask - you'll have to sweat before you fix that. (that's why I said that I hope that your problem is the first one).

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01858 is "a non-numeric character found where a digit was expected".

You are providing dates as string literals, and counting on them to match the database's current date format, which is a dodgy practice at best. Instead, you should explicitly convert them to dates:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO   vcount
FROM   base_sales_ordrer
WHERE  status_lkp = '2' AND 
       date_created BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-may-20', 'DD-MON-YY') AND
                            TO_DATE('31-may-20', 'DD-MON-YY')
```